# как получить полный путь к запрашиваемой странице в Django

Tags: django

Я получаю в адресной строке браузера путь к запрашиваемой странице такого вида

http://192.168.0.178:8000/customers-orders/37/customers-orders-date/?datefilter=06%2F14%2F2020+-+06%2F26%2F2020

Как мне получить этот путь в моем представлении (в views.py), чтобы дальше работать с ним там?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `build_absolute_uri` у объекта `request` [Документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri)